# Why does the adjoint exist for densely defined operators?

Tags: adjoint-operators

It is my understanding that when an operator is densely defined, then the adjoint operator exists. But, if $X,\, Y$ Banach spaces and  $A:D(A)\subset X\to Y$ linear operator.

Why is it necessary for $D(A)$ to be dense in $X$ to have an existence of the adjoint $A^*$?

If $D(A)$ is not dense in $X$, not necessarily the adjoint exists, right?

Comment: If $D(A)$ is not dense then the adjoint is not **uniquely** defined.

Comment: The adjoint holds $(A^*u,v)=(u,Av),\quad v\in D(A).$
If exists another $B^*$ such that $( B^*u,v)=(u,Av),\quad v\in D(A)$ then 
$(A^*u-B^*u,v)=0,\quad v\in D(A).$

How can use the dense property of $D(A)$  To demonstrate that $A^*=B^*$?

Comment: $(A^{*}u-B^{*u},v)=0$ for all $v \in D(A)$ implies that $(A^{*}u-B^{*u},v)=0$ for all $v \in X$ which implies that $A^{*}u-B^{*}u$ is orthogonal to itself Hence it is $0$.

Comment: I understood perfectly. $(A^*u-B^*u) \perp X$ then $A^*u-B^*u=0$.
But one last question arose. The adjoint is $A^*:D(A^*)\subset Y^*\to X^*$, $B^*:D(B^*)\subset Y^*\to X^*$. In principle, $u\in Y^*$ (is a functional in $Y$) then $A^*u,\, B^*u$ are functional in $X$.
What does it mean for a functional on $X$ to be perpendicular to $X$?

Comment: $A^{*}$ is a functional, $A^{*}u$ is an element of $X$.

Comment: I think I have it. 
If $f\in X^*, f\perp x$ means $(f,x)=0$ for all $x\in X$. Equivalent is $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$. Then $f=0$.

Comment: I had understood that
 $A^*:D(A^*)\subset Y^*\to X^*$... then $A^*u\in X^*$...

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. $A^{*}u \in X^{*}$.